# Navigation drawer on right side not staying open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using a slide-from-right `NavigationDrawer` to display some filters.  The problem is that the drawer on the right only stays open when doing a fling gesture.  If I change the gravity attribute to `start` or `left`, then it stays opened normally.  I consider normal to be where a slow drag and then letting go will keep the drawer open.  With drawers on the right, there seems to be a bias to the closed position.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a way to get it to slide normally?   My users are having trouble figuring out that they need to fling to keep the drawer open.

Using support library.

Requires fling:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filtersDrawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/drawer_color"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Doesn't require fling:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/filtersDrawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/drawer_color"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever come up with a better solution here? Right side NavigationDrawers seem extremely messed up. Even the official Google+ application rightside notifications drawer performs like shit.

Comment: nope.  looked breifly at the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java), didn't figure anything out, and gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using a listener and forcing the drawer open/closed when the user has dragged a certain percentage, and then released the drawer, as this:

```
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        private float mLastOffset;
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideOffset) {
            mLastOffset = slideOffset;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            if (newState == DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING) {
                if (mLastOffset > 0.5f) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
                } else {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks!  I made one change to your code.  I put `mLastOffset = 0;` in `onDrawerOpened()` so that the drawer will still close normally when pressing the area not covered.  I don't think this causes any other problems...

Comment: the drawer will still not close if you open the drawer and then slide it back a little and reopen it.  onDrawerOpened() is never called because the drawer is already open?  have to look into it more.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I've come up with the correct logic to address the deficiencies in the stock implementation.

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    /**
     * percentage of its width that the drawer needs to be open to
     * trigger a toggle (between 0 and 1).
     **/
    private static final float TOGGLE_OFFSET = 0.3f;

    private float lastSlideOffset;
    private boolean isDragging;

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float slideOffset) {
        lastSlideOffset = slideOffset;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {}

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {}

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case DrawerLayout.STATE_DRAGGING:
                isDragging = true;
                break;

            case DrawerLayout.STATE_IDLE:
                isDragging = false;
                break;

            case DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING:
                if (isDragging) {
                    attemptToggle();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void attemptToggle() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)) {
            if (lastSlideOffset <= 1 - TOGGLE_OFFSET) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
            }

        } else {
            if (lastSlideOffset >= TOGGLE_OFFSET) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
            }
        }
    }
});
```